# VM de VIRTUAL BOX Oracle no inicia

Tags: virtualbox

Venia trabajando normalmente con mis Vms, con Oracle VM Virtual Box.
Luego de una semana de no estar utilizandola, quise iniciar CUALQUIERA de mis vms y todas arrojan este error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado iniciar, con el inicio desacoplado y arroja este otro error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He probado desactivar algunas caracteristicas de windows que me han recomendado en otros foros, pero no ha funcionado.
Desconozco cual es el problema. Lo único que podría decirles es que instalé ayer un emulador de PS3, pero ya lo he desinstalado.
Cualquier información que necesiten para ayudarme, no duden en consultarlo.

Agrego una parte de los logs del vboxhardening.log

```
5c64.5da4: kernel32.dll: timestamp 0x9ec9da27 (rc=VINF_SUCCESS)
5c64.5da4: kernelbase.dll: timestamp 0xd80f8f12 (rc=VINF_SUCCESS)
5c64.5da4: apphelp.dll: timestamp 0xd7772866 (rc=VINF_SUCCESS)
5c64.5da4: VBoxHeadless.exe: timestamp 0x652832c2 (rc=VINF_SUCCESS)
5c64.5da4: \Device\HarddiskVolume9\Virtual Box\VBoxHeadless.exe: Signature #1/2: info status: 24202
5c64.5da4: '\Device\HarddiskVolume9\Virtual Box\VBoxHeadless.exe' has no imports
5c64.5da4: VBoxHeadless.exe: Differences in section #0 (headers) between file and memory:
5c64.5da4:   00007ff704a00040 / 0x0000040: 56 != 77
5c64.5da4:   00007ff704a00041 / 0x0000041: 69 != 72
5c64.5da4:   00007ff704a00042 / 0x0000042: 72 != 5c
5c64.5da4:   00007ff704a00043 / 0x0000043: 74 != 38
5c64.5da4:   00007ff704a00044 / 0x0000044: 75 != c0
5c64.5da4:   00007ff704a00045 / 0x0000045: 61 != a7
5c64.5da4:   00007ff704a00046 / 0x0000046: 6c != 1d
5c64.5da4:   00007ff704a00047 / 0x0000047: 42 != 02
5c64.5da4:   00007ff704a00048 / 0x0000048: 6f != 00
5c64.5da4:   00007ff704a00049 / 0x0000049: 78 != 00
5c64.5da4:   Restored 0x400 bytes of original file content at 00007ff704a00000
5c64.5da4: VBoxHeadless.exe: Differences in section #7 (.00cfg) between file and memory:
5c64.5da4:   00007ff704ad3000 / 0x00d3000: 00 != 20
5c64.5da4:   00007ff704ad3001 / 0x00d3001: 0b != c8
5c64.5da4:   00007ff704ad3002 / 0x00d3002: a2 != d3
5c64.5da4:   00007ff704ad3003 / 0x00d3003: 04 != ab
5c64.5da4:   00007ff704ad3004 / 0x00d3004: f7 != fe
5c64.5da4:   00007ff704ad3010 / 0x00d3010: 30 != c0
5c64.5da4:   00007ff704ad3011 / 0x00d3011: a8 != c8
5c64.5da4:   00007ff704ad3012 / 0x00d3012: a6 != d3
5c64.5da4:   00007ff704ad3013 / 0x00d3013: 04 != ab
5c64.5da4:   00007ff704ad3014 / 0x00d3014: f7 != fe
5c64.5da4:   Restored 0x28 bytes of original file content at 00007ff704ad3000
5c64.5da4: VBoxHeadless.exe: Differences in section #8 (.rsrc) between file and memory:
5c64.5da4:   00007ff704b125f8 / 0x01125f8: 00 != 50
5c64.5da4:   00007ff704b125f9 / 0x01125f9: 00 != 41
5c64.5da4:   00007ff704b125fa / 0x01125fa: 00 != 44
5c64.5da4:   00007ff704b125fb / 0x01125fb: 00 != 44
5c64.5da4:   00007ff704b125fc / 0x01125fc: 00 != 49
5c64.5da4:   00007ff704b125fd / 0x01125fd: 00 != 4e
5c64.5da4:   00007ff704b125fe / 0x01125fe: 00 != 47
5c64.5da4:   00007ff704b125ff / 0x01125ff: 00 != 58
5c64.5da4:   Restored 0xa08 bytes of original file content at 00007ff704b125f8
5c64.5da4: '\Device\HarddiskVolume6\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll' has no imports
5c64.5da4: ntdll.dll: Differences in section #1 (.text) between file and memory:
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeabd4d0b0 / 0x009d0b0: 4c != e9
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeabd4d0b1 / 0x009d0b1: 8b != 23
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeabd4d0b2 / 0x009d0b2: d1 != 34
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeabd4d0b3 / 0x009d0b3: b8 != fe
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeabd4d0b4 / 0x009d0b4: 07 != bf
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeabd4d0b5 / 0x009d0b5: 00 != cc
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeabd4d0b6 / 0x009d0b6: 00 != cc
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeabd4d0b7 / 0x009d0b7: 00 != cc
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeabd4d230 / 0x009d230: 4c != e9
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeabd4d231 / 0x009d231: 8b != 23
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeabd4d232 / 0x009d232: d1 != 31
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeabd4d233 / 0x009d233: b8 != fe
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeabd4d234 / 0x009d234: 13 != bf
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeabd4d235 / 0x009d235: 00 != cc
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeabd4d236 / 0x009d236: 00 != cc
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeabd4d237 / 0x009d237: 00 != cc
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeabd4d610 / 0x009d610: 4c != e9
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeabd4d611 / 0x009d611: 8b != e3
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeabd4d612 / 0x009d612: d1 != 2c
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeabd4d613 / 0x009d613: b8 != fe
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeabd4d614 / 0x009d614: 32 != bf
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeabd4d615 / 0x009d615: 00 != cc
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeabd4d616 / 0x009d616: 00 != cc
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeabd4d617 / 0x009d617: 00 != cc
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeabd4d670 / 0x009d670: 4c != e9
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeabd4d671 / 0x009d671: 8b != c3
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeabd4d672 / 0x009d672: d1 != 2b
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeabd4d673 / 0x009d673: b8 != fe
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeabd4d674 / 0x009d674: 35 != bf
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeabd4d675 / 0x009d675: 00 != cc
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeabd4d676 / 0x009d676: 00 != cc
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeabd4d677 / 0x009d677: 00 != cc
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeabd4d690 / 0x009d690: 4c != e9
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeabd4d691 / 0x009d691: 8b != e3
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeabd4d692 / 0x009d692: d1 != 2a
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeabd4d693 / 0x009d693: b8 != fe
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeabd4d694 / 0x009d694: 36 != bf
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeabd4d695 / 0x009d695: 00 != cc
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeabd4d696 / 0x009d696: 00 != cc
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeabd4d697 / 0x009d697: 00 != cc
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeabd4da10 / 0x009da10: 4c != e9
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeabd4da11 / 0x009da11: 8b != c3
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeabd4da12 / 0x009da12: d1 != 27
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeabd4da13 / 0x009da13: b8 != fe
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeabd4da14 / 0x009da14: 52 != bf
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeabd4da15 / 0x009da15: 00 != cc
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeabd4da16 / 0x009da16: 00 != cc
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeabd4da17 / 0x009da17: 00 != cc
5c64.5da4:   Restored 0x2000 bytes of original file content at 00007ffeabd4cbee
5c64.5da4: ntdll.dll: Differences in section #1 (.text) between file and memory:
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeabd4f820 / 0x009f820: 4c != e9
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeabd4f821 / 0x009f821: 8b != 73
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeabd4f822 / 0x009f822: d1 != 0a
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeabd4f823 / 0x009f823: b8 != fe
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeabd4f824 / 0x009f824: 43 != bf
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeabd4f825 / 0x009f825: 01 != cc
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeabd4f826 / 0x009f826: 00 != cc
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeabd4f827 / 0x009f827: 00 != cc
5c64.5da4:   Restored 0x2000 bytes of original file content at 00007ffeabd4ebee
5c64.5da4: ntdll.dll: Differences in section #8 (.00cfg) between file and memory:
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeabe35000 / 0x0185000: f0 != c0
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeabe35001 / 0x0185001: 0a != c8
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeabe35002 / 0x0185002: d5 != d3
5c64.5da4:   Restored 0x8 bytes of original file content at 00007ffeabe35000
5c64.5da4: kernel32.dll: Differences in section #2 (.rdata) between file and memory:
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeaa822748 / 0x0082748: c0 != b0
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeaa822749 / 0x0082749: db != 22
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeaa82274a / 0x008274a: d4 != c1
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeaa82274b / 0x008274b: ab != a6
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeaa822b50 / 0x0082b50: b0 != 20
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeaa822b51 / 0x0082b51: d4 != 22
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeaa822b52 / 0x0082b52: d4 != c1
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeaa822b53 / 0x0082b53: ab != a6
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeaa822ce0 / 0x0082ce0: 70 != 30
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeaa822ce1 / 0x0082ce1: da != 20
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeaa822ce2 / 0x0082ce2: d4 != c1
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeaa822ce3 / 0x0082ce3: ab != a6
5c64.5da4:   Restored 0x2000 bytes of original file content at 00007ffeaa821000
5c64.5da4: kernel32.dll: Differences in section #2 (.rdata) between file and memory:
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeaa8230e0 / 0x00830e0: 70 != 30
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeaa8230e1 / 0x00830e1: da != 20
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeaa8230e2 / 0x00830e2: d4 != c1
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeaa8230e3 / 0x00830e3: ab != a6
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeaa823230 / 0x0083230: c0 != 20
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeaa823231 / 0x0083231: 68 != c8
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeaa823232 / 0x0083232: 7c != d3
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeaa823233 / 0x0083233: aa != ab
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeaa823238 / 0x0083238: e0 != c0
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeaa823239 / 0x0083239: 6a != c8
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeaa82323a / 0x008323a: 7c != d3
5c64.5da4:   00007ffeaa82323b / 0x008323b: aa != ab
5c64.5da4:   Restored 0x2000 bytes of original file content at 00007ffeaa823000
5c64.5da4: kernelbase.dll: Differences in section #2 (.rdata) between file and memory:
5c64.5da4:   00007ffea9864960 / 0x01e4960: b0 != 20
5c64.5da4:   00007ffea9864961 / 0x01e4961: d4 != 22
5c64.5da4:   00007ffea9864962 / 0x01e4962: d4 != c1
5c64.5da4:   00007ffea9864963 / 0x01e4963: ab != a6
5c64.5da4:   00007ffea9864998 / 0x01e4998: 70 != 30
5c64.5da4:   00007ffea9864999 / 0x01e4999: da != 20
5c64.5da4:   00007ffea986499a / 0x01e499a: d4 != c1
5c64.5da4:   00007ffea986499b / 0x01e499b: ab != a6
5c64.5da4:   00007ffea9864ad8 / 0x01e4ad8: c0 != b0
5c64.5da4:   00007ffea9864ad9 / 0x01e4ad9: db != 22
5c64.5da4:   00007ffea9864ada / 0x01e4ada: d4 != c1
5c64.5da4:   00007ffea9864adb / 0x01e4adb: ab != a6
5c64.5da4:   00007ffea9865260 / 0x01e5260: c0 != b0
5c64.5da4:   00007ffea9865261 / 0x01e5261: db != 22
5c64.5da4:   00007ffea9865262 / 0x01e5262: d4 != c1
5c64.5da4:   00007ffea9865263 / 0x01e5263: ab != a6
5c64.5da4:   00007ffea9865e90 / 0x01e5e90: 80 != 20
5c64.5da4:   00007ffea9865e91 / 0x01e5e91: 67 != c8
5c64.5da4:   00007ffea9865e92 / 0x01e5e92: 73 != d3
5c64.5da4:   00007ffea9865e93 / 0x01e5e93: a9 != ab
5c64.5da4:   00007ffea9865e98 / 0x01e5e98: 30 != c0
5c64.5da4:   00007ffea9865e99 / 0x01e5e99: 6b != c8
5c64.5da4:   00007ffea9865e9a / 0x01e5e9a: 73 != d3
5c64.5da4:   00007ffea9865e9b / 0x01e5e9b: a9 != ab
5c64.5da4:   Restored 0x2000 bytes of original file content at 00007ffea9864000
5c64.5da4: apphelp.dll: Differences in section #2 (.rdata) between file and memory:
5c64.5da4:   00007ffea6c20e88 / 0x0050e88: 00 != 70
5c64.5da4:   00007ffea6c20e89 / 0x0050e89: 96 != ce
5c64.5da4:   00007ffea6c20e8a / 0x0050e8a: 6d != 7b
5c64.5da4:   00007ffea6c20e8b / 0x0050e8b: a9 != aa
5c64.5da4:   00007ffea6c20e90 / 0x0050e90: b0 != 00
5c64.5da4:   00007ffea6c20e91 / 0x0050e91: f5 != cb
5c64.5da4:   00007ffea6c20e92 / 0x0050e92: 6e != 7b
5c64.5da4:   00007ffea6c20e93 / 0x0050e93: a9 != aa
5c64.5da4:   00007ffea6c20e98 / 0x0050e98: b0 != 60
5c64.5da4:   00007ffea6c20e99 / 0x0050e99: 05 != 58
5c64.5da4:   00007ffea6c20e9a / 0x0050e9a: 69 != 7b
5c64.5da4:   00007ffea6c20e9b / 0x0050e9b: a9 != aa
5c64.5da4:   00007ffea6c20ea0 / 0x0050ea0: 60 != a0
5c64.5da4:   00007ffea6c20ea1 / 0x0050ea1: 42 != 4b
5c64.5da4:   00007ffea6c20ea2 / 0x0050ea2: 6d != 7c
5c64.5da4:   00007ffea6c20ea3 / 0x0050ea3: a9 != aa
5c64.5da4:   00007ffea6c20ea8 / 0x0050ea8: 30 != e0
5c64.5da4:   00007ffea6c20ea9 / 0x0050ea9: ca != ad
5c64.5da4:   00007ffea6c20eaa / 0x0050eaa: 6e != 7b
5c64.5da4:   00007ffea6c20eab / 0x0050eab: a9 != aa
5c64.5da4:   00007ffea6c20eb0 / 0x0050eb0: d0 != 90
5c64.5da4:   00007ffea6c20eb1 / 0x0050eb1: cb != 4b
5c64.5da4:   00007ffea6c20eb2 / 0x0050eb2: 6b != 7c
5c64.5da4:   00007ffea6c20eb3 / 0x0050eb3: a9 != aa
5c64.5da4:   00007ffea6c20eb8 / 0x0050eb8: 80 != 70
5c64.5da4:   00007ffea6c20eb9 / 0x0050eb9: 47 != 0a
5c64.5da4:   00007ffea6c20eba / 0x0050eba: 70 != 7c
5c64.5da4:   00007ffea6c20ebb / 0x0050ebb: a9 != aa
5c64.5da4:   00007ffea6c20ec8 / 0x0050ec8: a0 != f0
5c64.5da4:   00007ffea6c20ec9 / 0x0050ec9: 08 != b0
5c64.5da4:   00007ffea6c20eca / 0x0050eca: 6b != 7b
5c64.5da4:   00007ffea6c20ecb / 0x0050ecb: a9 != aa
5c64.5da4:   Restored 0x2000 bytes of original file content at 00007ffea6c1f000
5c64.5da4: apphelp.dll: Differences in section #2 (.rdata) between file and memory:
5c64.5da4:   00007ffea6c21468 / 0x0051468: 90 != 20
5c64.5da4:   00007ffea6c21469 / 0x0051469: 0b != c8
5c64.5da4:   00007ffea6c2146a / 0x005146a: be != d3
5c64.5da4:   00007ffea6c2146b / 0x005146b: a6 != ab
5c64.5da4:   00007ffea6c21470 / 0x0051470: 00 != c0
5c64.5da4:   00007ffea6c21471 / 0x0051471: 0d != c8
5c64.5da4:   00007ffea6c21472 / 0x0051472: be != d3
5c64.5da4:   00007ffea6c21473 / 0x0051473: a6 != ab
5c64.5da4:   Restored 0x2000 bytes of original file content at 00007ffea6c21000
5c64.5da4: supHardNtVpCheckHandles:
5c64.5da4: supHardNtVpCheckHandles: Inheritable file handle: 0000000000000058
5c64.5da4: supHardNtVpCheckHandles: Inheritable file handle: 0000000000000054
5c64.5da4: supHardNtVpCheckHandles: Inheritable file handle: 0000000000000050
5c64.5da4: supR3HardenedWinInit: SUPHARDNTVPKIND_SELF_PURIFICATION_LIMITED -> VINF_SUCCESS, cFixes=11
5c64.5da4: \Device\HarddiskVolume9\Virtual Box\VBoxHeadless.exe: Signature #1/2: info status: 24202
5c64.5da4: '\Device\HarddiskVolume9\Virtual Box\VBoxHeadless.exe' has no imports
5c64.5da4: supHardenedWinVerifyImageByHandle: -> 24202 (\Device\HarddiskVolume9\Virtual Box\VBoxHeadless.exe)
5c64.5da4: supR3HardNtEnableThreadCreationEx:
5c64.5da4: supR3HardNtDisableThreadCreation: pvLdrInitThunk=00007ffeabd24be0 pvNtTerminateThread=00007ffeabd4da30
5c64.5da4: supR3HardenedWinDoReSpawn(1): New child 125c.36b4 [kernel32].
5c64.5da4: supR3HardNtChildGatherData: PebBaseAddress=000000aeaabff000 cbPeb=0x388
5c64.5da4: supR3HardNtPuChFindNtdll: uNtDllParentAddr=00007ffeabcb0000 uNtDllChildAddr=00007ffeabcb0000
5c64.5da4: supR3HardenedWinSetupChildInit: uLdrInitThunk=00007ffeabd24be0
5c64.5da4: supR3HardenedWinSetupChildInit: Initial context:
  rax=0000000000000000 rbx=0000000000000000 rcx=00007ff704a0b5a0 rdx=000000aeaabff000
  rsi=0000000000000000 rdi=0000000000000000 r8 =0000000000000000 r9 =0000000000000000
  r10=0000000000000000 r11=0000000000000000 r12=0000000000000000 r13=0000000000000000
  r14=0000000000000000 r15=0000000000000000  P1=0000000000000000  P2=0000000000000000
  rip=00007ffeabd02690 rsp=000000aeaacff918 rbp=0000000000000000    ctxflags=0010001b
  cs=0033 ss=002b ds=0000 es=0000 fs=0000 gs=0000    eflags=00000200   mxcrx=00001f80
   P3=0000000000000000  P4=0000000000000000  P5=0000000000000000  P6=0000000000000000
  dr0=0000000000000000 dr1=0000000000000000 dr2=0000000000000000 dr3=0000000000000000
  dr6=0000000000000000 dr7=0000000000000000 vcr=0000000000000000 dcr=0000000000000000
  lbt=0000000000000000 lbf=0000000000000000 lxt=0000000000000000 lxf=0000000000000000
5c64.5da4: supR3HardenedWinSetupChildInit: Start child.
5c64.5da4: supR3HardNtChildWaitFor: Found expected request 0 (PurifyChildAndCloseHandles) after 0 ms.
5c64.5da4: supR3HardNtChildPurify: Startup delay kludge #1/0: 270 ms, 17 sleeps
5c64.5da4: supHardNtVpScanVirtualMemory: enmKind=CHILD_PURIFICATION
5c64.5da4: Error (rc=-5637):
5c64.5da4: NtQueryVirtualMemory failed for 0000000000000000: 0xc000010a
5c64.5da4: Error (rc=-5637):
5c64.5da4: supHardenedWinVerifyProcess failed with -5637: NtQueryVirtualMemory failed for 0000000000000000: 0xc000010a
5c64.5da4: Error -5637 in supR3HardNtChildPurify! (enmWhat=5)
5c64.5da4: supHardenedWinVerifyProcess failed with -5637: NtQueryVirtualMemory failed for 0000000000000000: 0xc000010a
3768.5654: Terminating the normal way: rcExit=0
```

Comment: si falla el hardening puede ser que algún proceso esté cambiando data en memoria, fijate si el "emulador" no dejó algun service o rootkit. en el log `(...vmfolder..)/Logs/VBoxHardening.log` seguramente te da una pista de que DLLs no pasan la prueba.

Comment: Ahí actualicé con una parte de los logs, ya que no podría poner todo el archivo. No comprendo el archivo del todo, por eso lo añadí

Comment: seguramente el emulador desactivó alguna cosa del defender para poder funcionar y se olvidó de activarlo al desinstalar. el log es bastante normal salvo el fallo en el pedido de status de memoria virtual `supHardNtVpScanVirtualMemory` ahi puede q este el asunto

Answer (score 0):

No sé qué tendrá que ver. Pero lo corregí instalando Avast en mi equipo. Aparentemente la seguridad de windows que viene por defecto, no estaba funcionando correctamente, e instalando avast se corrigió.